# Getting error "The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded" while moving from a dialog to another many times in Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: c#, botframework, botframeworkemulator

The problem appears when moving from one dialog to another many times or even when looping in the same dialog. After looping in the same dialog 9 times with many prompts inside it. An error raiesd from "OnTurnError"

```
value:"The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded. Path 'DialogState.dialogStack.$values\[0\].
state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].s
tate.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].
state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].
state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.dialogs.dialogStack.$values\[0\].state.options.Prompt.attachments.$values'."
```

I tried to empty the stack, change the MaxDepth but nothing changed. Is there any way to manage a long conversation with many prompts without getting this error.

Comment: Could you please share the code on how you changed the `MaxDepth` in startup.cs?

Comment: @RamFattah ` public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient().AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = HttpHelper.BotMessageSerializerSettings.MaxDepth;
            });`  the value should be updated to 128 but nothing changed.

Comment: @Mohammed Amin, could you try the following code to see if it helps:

`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
     options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = null;
 });`

Comment: @RamFattah, unfortunately I got the same error. Actually, I think this problem is related to newtonsoft.json package v13 because when I downgrade the package to v12 and downgrade all of the other packages to be suitble for newtonsoft.json v12 the bot runs properly. But I think this solution won't be valid for a long time as some packages will be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

When I pass dialog Id paramter for ReplaceDialogAsync method that starts the loop with InitialDialogId which is equals to nameof(WaterfallDialog) instead of nameof(ReviewSelectionDialog) which is the name of dialog that I want to repeat, the bot runs properly. But I  still don't know why the new code works properly!

- Previous code

```
return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(ReviewSelectionDialog), userProfile, cancellationToken);
```

- Modified

```
return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId, userProfile, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: asking to clarify; using `InitialDialogId` instead of `nameof(ReviewSelectionDialog)` solved the issue?

Comment: @RamFattah Yes, but I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: Changing the MaxDepth was not working for me either, until I upgraded the bot framework version to [4.19.0](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases/tag/4.19.0) or later.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs" Version="4.19.0" />
```

After doing this the example code did work.

```
services.AddHttpClient().AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = HttpHelper.BotMessageSerializerSettings.MaxDepth;
});
```